# Inteliij - searching in the whole project - replace all characters

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, formatting

Using IntelliJ IDEA I am facing a problem while searching in the whole project for a file with some text.

I click `ctrl` + `Shift` + `F` and I would like to find rows where are `div`s with `class="X"` but I don't know the correct order.

I would like to write something like that: `div*class="X"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and type in the search bar `(div).*(class="X")`.

In case the class `X` can be located anywhere in the string, for instance:

`<div class="another-class X"></div>`

change your regex like this: `(div).*(class=".*X")`

Also, make sure you have selected the property *Regex* (see below image).

For instance here I searched for all html files where there is a `div` with `class="row"`.

[image]

---

I've used this on *IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-181.5281.24* and it works like charm.